# Python DataFrame split result in NaN

Tags: python, dataframe, split

I want to split DataFrame by delimiter. but the result is 'NaN'.

this is dataframe that imported from blf with can.BLFReader.

code is here:

```
import can
import pandas as pd

filename = "test.blf"               # test file directory
log = can.BLFReader(filename)       # import blf file
df = pd.DataFrame(log)              # make DataFrame
df['Time'] = df[0].str.split(' ')

print(df)
```

the result is below

[image]

Is there anything wrong?

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: I want to separate the dataframe to each columns, e.g 'Timestamp', 'ID' ...